# Visual Studio macOS can't generate HTML documentation for Xamarin.Forms app

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.forms, visual-studio-mac

I have created a Xamarin.Forms application on a Mac, and I understand that there's a way to generate the methods and classes documentation into HTML. But most of the tools mentioned online do not seem to work on Visual Studio for macOS.

I've tried the recommended eVisual Studio Extensions MacOS version of Visual Studio does not seem to be able to implement Visual Studio extensions ( .vsix files).

Is there a way to generate documentation in Visual Studio?
Or do I have to move the project to a Windows machine with Visual Studio to Generate the docs?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are a number of cross-platform html generation tools that support the XML document schema that MSBuild produces via:

- globally in a solution via `GenerateDocumentationFile` in a prop file
- the `DocumentationFile` filename property in individual projects `.csproj`

Tools such as  Doxygen, DocFX, etc.. run on Windows|macOS|Linux, but these tools, outside of Windows, are mainly cmd-line based.

The ones that I use:

- https://dotnet.github.io/docfx/
- http://www.doxygen.nl

Do a Google/Bing for more alternatives.

Comment: Thanks for the great answer, I've installed docfx and using it in the terminal. I'm not able to --serve the docs though, I keep getting many errors and warrnings : 
   PROJECT.csproj)Error opening project PROJECT.csproj: Could not load type of field 'Microsoft.CodeAnalysis.SQLite.Interop.SqlConnection:_handle' (0) due to: Could not load file or assembly 'SQLitePCLRaw.core, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=1488e028ca7ab535' or one of its dependencies.. Ignored.  is this normal, do I need to add anything specific to the project itself.

Comment: I mean does DocFX only work after adding  GenerateDocumentationFile in a prop file or DocumentationFile in .csproj ? thanks

Comment: @Tlink I use the XML generated docs, so I am not sure what that error is..(?)